# How run artisan commands from Host with docker containers

Tags: laravel, docker

It is possible run "php artisan commands" from Host if the server is running into container, and how?

Comment: Why do you want to run this command from the host and not from the container? this is the purpose of containerizing your application.

Comment: Because is more confortable

Comment: Ok, to be honest, I am able to run "php artisan migrate" from host no need enter to container, but only in my Linux box (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: In this link you can see this: https://forums.docker.com/t/why-i-can-run-php-artisan-migrate-from-ubuntu-host-and-not-from-windows/46136

Answer (score 15):

To run commands from your host,

You can use Docker's [`exec`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/exec/) command like this:

```
docker exec -it my-container-name /bin/bash
```

After that, you can run any command you want

```
php artisan --version
```

Comment: or docker exec -it my-container-name php artisan --version

Comment: I don't refer to that, I mean if is possible without enter to container. From host, means from host

Comment: Time ago, I was able to run migrations from host in my Windows 10 Pro, but I had to format and loss docker configurations. Now I can run no need enter to container, but only in my Linux Ubuntu 16.04 PC... I have been trying to find why and how of this but all the people answer with the same: "docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash". I know that way to run into container if not the microservice could has a trouble. Anyway thanks

Answer (score 8):

You'd need to change the path references to suit your own project, but this allows you to execute the artisan command from your host machine on the container without having to login.

```
docker exec -it <php-fpm-container> /var/www/html/artisan
```

Comment: I use something like `docker-compose exec app php artisan dusk` *(where `app` is the name under `services:` in your `docker-compose.yml` file)*

Answer (score 0):

Client (`php artisan`) on the host talking to server in a container is a solved problem:

This can be done in two ways. They make the server's port in the container accessible on the host:

1. Publish the server's port to the host by passing `-p` to `docker run`. More info is [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#entrypoint-default-command-to-execute-at-runtime).

   ```
   docker run -p hostPort:containerPort ...
   ```
2. Use Docker's "**host networking**" by passing `--network host` to `docker run`. More info is [here](https://docs.docker.com/network/network-tutorial-host/).

   ```
   docker run --network host ...
   ```

Answer (score 0):

if using `docker-compose`

1. first get into the container

```
docker-compose exec <container_name|id> bash
```

2. now goto var/www/html directory and run your choice of command

Answer (score 0):

when using **package.json** you could place it inside the "scripts" like

```
{
 ...
 "scripts":{
  "artisan": "docker exec -it CONTAINER-NAME php artisan --command process.env.command"
 }
...
}
```

then you could execute artisan-commands like that:

**migrate:**

```
npm run artisan migrate
```

**version**

```
npm run artisan --version
```

Answer (score 0):

cd on my project

```
cd /Users/neisantos/src/laravel-project
```

considering I have a docker running using the name [APP]

```
alias artisan='[ -d /Users/neisantos/src/laravel-project ] && docker exec -it APP php artisan'
```

so I can only do the command below to execute artisan from my docker container.

```
artisan route:list
```

this alias will run only when running from the folder of my project.

Answer (score -3):

**This is the solution!** Ok, for a while, I thought I was crazy, but I did not. The trick is set a PHP into host (for the CLI), matching with the docker PHP version, so:
[image: This image shows how the trick works]